# Should answers stick to canon manga/anime content or can filler episodes in anime be used as reference material

Tags: discussion

In reference to the question [Did Itachi know that Shisui had a Mangekyo Sharingan?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/8853/did-itachi-know-that-shisui-had-a-mangekyo-sharingan), is it acceptable if the answer is based completely on canon manga content, or is it safe to bring references from the filler episodes in the anime.

If the answer is based on canon manga content then there are a lot of speculations that can seep into the answer. However, if content from the filler episodes are referenced then the answer can be more firm and reliable. But there can be some ambiguity in filler episodes and may cause the answer to be ambiguous.

Also, this is one case where we do not have separate tags for anime and manga, and since both the genres point to the same tag, the answers tend to refer contents from both manga and anime.

What would be the correct way to tread these shores?

Answer (score 4):

I think that filler episodes can be referenced, but if it matters that filler is being referenced, it should be made clear that the information is coming from filler. You can do something like put it as a footnote or have one line saying "this is from x episode, which is a filler episode." It will allow for a complete answer while letting anyone who cares know that the information is not 100% from canon manga content.